# C++ modules: Multiply defined symbols no longer an error?

Tags: c++

If you have two classic translation units which both define the same symbol (let's say `auto fun0() -> void`), I get a `fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found` in MSVC as it violates the ODR.

One of the first steps I made with C++ modules was trying out the behavior with that basic principle. So we have two module files (`module0.ixx` and `module1.ixx`) with this almost identical content:

```
// module0.ixx
export module module0;
import <cstdio>;
export void f_test() { printf("f_test()\n"); }

// module1.ixx
export module module1;
import <cstdio>;
export void f_test() { printf("f_test()\n"); }
```

In my `main.cpp`, I do

```
import module0;
import module1;
auto main() -> int{
    f_test();
}
```

To my surprise, this compiles just fine. With that come the expected problems: If the definition is different, the behavior depends on the order etc. Is this expected? This was 5 minutes into playing around with modules and seems pretty baffling.

Comment: FWIW, clang permits multiple definitions in different modules only as long as the definitions are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Multiply defined symbols no longer an error?"* - They were never required to be an error. Violation of the ODR is "ill-formed; no diagnostic required". Which basically means undefined behavior ensues, like you see here.

This issue is not specifically endemic to modules. "Old C++" can exhibit the same behavior.

```cpp
// oops_header.h
#ifndef OOPS
#error OOPS
#endif

#include <iostream>

inline void oops_func() { std::cout << OOPS; }
```

And we the same shenanigans when we include it and mess with the macro

```cpp
// tu1.cpp
#define OOPS 123
#include <oops_header.h>
void a() { oops_func(); }

// tu2.cpp
#define OOPS 42
#include <oops_header.h>
void b() { oops_func(); }
```

Where a main function like this

```cpp
extern void a();
extern void b();
int main() {
  a();
  b();
}
```

Will exhibit the exact same problems you encountered with the modules. The output will depend on the stars, because I violated the ODR (inline functions are required by the ODR to be identical on the token level).

You see it with modules due to an artefact of their implementation today (kinda similar to precompiled headers).

Comment: And yes, I went out of my way to break the ODR in an "undetectable" way, but it is only because there is no requirement to detect it. I broke an agreement where the compiler trusted me to behave sensibly.

Comment: I did legit not know that. That is disappointing, but good to know. Thank you

Comment: Still, C++ implementations usually do provide diagnostics for multiply defined "old C++" non-inline functions and variables with external linkage. This is a regression, regardless of what the standard says.

Comment: @n.m. - Can't regress when the thing didn't exist before. TUs and module units interact in... not obvious ways, I'd say.

Comment: @n.m. -- duplicated names in separate libraries typically don't trigger error messages. That's the usual mechanism for replacing global `operator new` and `operator delete`, for example.

Comment: @PeteBecker This doesn't work like replacing global new/delete mechanism at all.  If you add `void f0() { f_test(); }` to `module0` and  `void f1() { f_test(); }` to `module1`, and call both `f0` and `f1` from `main`, `f0` will call `f_test` from `module0`, `f1` will call `f_test` from `module1`, and `main` will call whichever `f_test` is imported first (similarly to Windows DLLs). This is rather unfortunate.

Comment: @n.m. -- I was talking about how linking works in what you call "old C++"; once a symbol has been resolved, linkers typically ignore duplicate definitions in library modules that aren't otherwise pulled in.

Comment: @PeteBecker if a libtary module (object in linker-parlance) ia not pulled in, it is simply not a part of the program and ODR does not apply to it.

Comment: @n.m. -- that is, at best, a gloss; there is nothing in the standard about libraries (in that sense), and linking with a library makes names in that library visible to the linker. There is nothing in the standard that says that the linker must not report an error for such a program. There is, of course, lots of tradition here, and any linker that refused to link that program would not be at all popular. <g> But this is getting far afield from your question.

Comment: @PeteBecker You need to decide at some point what is a part of your program and what is not. The standatd doesn't dictate this decision. If you decide that the entire library you pass to the linker is a part of the program, then you must avoid using *all* names defined by unrelated parts of that library, otherwise your program has UB for no good reason at all.

Comment: @n.m. -- how does the compiler/linker know what you decided? You don't ordinarily tell the linker which parts of a library to use; it paws through the entire library to see what's useful.

Comment: @PeteBecker You may decide that whatever the linker actually pulled in is the part of the program, and whatever it didn't, isn't. (You know how the linker pulls in stuff, it is in the manual; you can reconstruct the list manually if you want to). Or you may have some alternative decision procedure. I don't know of any sane ones.